# Get list of fonts (Win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

I want to make a combo box with all of the computer's installed fonts enumerated in it. I'm not sure how this is done. Do I need to access the registry to get this?
Thanks

Comment: Great solution in C# here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486546/enumerating-active-fonts-in-c-sharp-using-dll-call-to-enumfontfamiliesex-has-me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the Win32 API function [EnumFontFamiliesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162620%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You call that function, passing a callback function matching the type of [EnumFontFamExProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162618%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The callback function is called once for every font found by EnumFontFamiliesEx.

I'd recommend using the unicode version (EnumFontFamiliesExW), as I've seen the ascii version (EnumFontFamiliesExA) display some very weird behaviour for East Asian language fonts.

The linked articles have example code.

Answer (score 5):

The winapi way of doing it is using `EnumFontFamiliesEx` function. You should pass a filled structure with default param `DEFAULT_CHARSET` to list all installed fonts.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162620%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get more information.